# Create Duplicate data based on total data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't understand how to duplicate data based on the total of the data, can you help me to solve this problem, thank you

| text | total |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |

Result

---

| text |
| --- |
| A |
| A |
| B |

Comment: can you share your latest coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: What is the maximum number of rows you'll need to replicate?

Comment: This case solved, and this is my query  
/*;
WITH CTE ([VALUE], totalTrx, startnum) AS(  
  SELECT [VALUE], totalTrx, [startnum] = 1   
  FROM @transactionTable 
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT [VALUE], totalTrx, [startnum] = (startnum + 1)  
  FROM CTE  
  WHERE (startnum + 1) <= totalTrx  
 )  */